# .NET Lock Performance Counters Difference

Tags: .net, windows, performancecounter

What is the difference between the "Total # of Contentions" and "Queue Length Peak" windows performance counters in the ".NET CLR LocksAndThreads" category?  MSDN Documentation is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat.aspx.

I think my confusion is about the difference between "the number of threads that tried to acquire a lock unsuccessfully" vs "the total number of threads that waited to acquire a managed lock since the application started."  In essence, what is the difference between waiting to acquire a lock, which I interpret as meaning someone else is holding it when you try to acquire it, and trying to acquire a lock unsuccessfully??  The only thing I can think of would be related to how lock acquisition is attempted, e.g. Monitor.TryEnter vs. Monitor.Enter.

Comment: I think they are measuring different things.  Contentions is a count of incidents and Queue Length is a count of threads.  Perhaps Contentions is the number of times a lock could not be acquired immediately and Queue Length is the number of threads that could not acquire a lock immediately.

Comment: What I'm confused about is when a thread fails to acquire a lock immediately how it does not count towards both counts -- in other words, each failed lock acquisition is both an instance of a thread failing to acquire a lock immediately and an instance of a lock failing to be acquired immediately.  The application in question has a "Queue Length Peak" value of 148,411, while the "Total # of Contentions" is only 255.

Comment: I read that Monitor is implemented first as a spin lock, then after a certain amount of time it goes into a wait state.  Perhaps one counter is the number of times the spin lock succeeded and the other is the number of times it failed.  I've got no idea; the documentation is not clear.

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't considered an optimistic spin locking implementation.  Do you happen to know and/or have a link to where you came across that information about the .NET monitor implementation?

Comment: Here is [one random blog entry](http://codingndesign.com/blog/?p=171) I found.  You could always disassemble the Monitor class and see for yourself what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would think of 3 scenarios when trying to acquire lock:
a) resource no locked by other entity, acquired immediately
b) resource locked, but released on time, acquired with delay
c) resource locked, but not released on time, acquisition times out

Total # of Contentions - total of scenario (c)
Queue Length Peak - at any given time the most threads in state (b)